# Can't get mySQL to put in number as new column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm trying to get numbers from a form to become a new column in a mySQL database.
Here is my form:

```
<form action="henkehaxx.php" method="post">
    Anvnamn: <input type="text" name="anvnamn"><br>
    Drinkid: <input type="number" name="drinkid"><br>
    Betyg: <input type="number" name="betyg">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So far I have this which works perfectly for creating new columns (and ignoring when the column already exists):

```
mysql_query("ALTER IGNORE TABLE drinkbetyg ADD $_POST[anvnamn] VARCHAR(20)")
```

But I want to have the drinkid (from the form) be a new column so therefore I expect something like this to work:

```
mysql_query("ALTER IGNORE TABLE drinkbetyg ADD $_POST[drinkid] INT")
```

But it doesn't.

I've tried with many variations like INT, TINYINT, INT(20), VARCHAR(20) and changing the type of value in the html form to text, but the problem seems to persist as long as drinkid only contains numbers.

Why doesn't it work?
What can I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no use case where dynamically adding columns with numerical names is a good RDBMS practice.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d... especially since you'd have to running with you mysql user having ALTER privileges, which is generally a BAD thing for web-facing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add a column that has a name that is an `INT`, something like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE drinkbetyg ADD 15 INT;
```

That doesn't work, because identifiers in MySQL have [certain rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html) that disallow naked numeric identifiers. That looks very, very strange to me, and is **probably not what you want to do**.

If, however, it is what you want to do, then wrap backticks around the number first:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE drinkbetyg ADD `15` INT;
```

...which, in your PHP, looks like this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE drinkbetyg ADD `$_POST[drinkid]` INT
```

If it is really, really what you want to do, then it's likely that you're solving a problem in the wrong way, because this is a highly unusual and probably very bad practice.

Comment: I don't disagree. Let me add emphasis in the answer to make that point.

Comment: Thanks. This works well, so I'm happy (for now). Maybe you could give me a clue as to why this might backfire?

Comment: I'm guessing you've got a column in the table for each drink ID. One problem with that is that you can't predict in advance how many columns the table will have at any time, and that'll get in the way of your backups, of any number of queries or modifications, and is generally not the way a relational database works. Rather, create a table for drinks, and another table for ratings (linked to the drink ID), and use relationships to connect the two distinct concepts "drink" and "rating". Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form for a discussion on breaking separate concepts.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into what all that means. Thanks for the heads up!